# Immediate write JSON API response to file with Python Requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests, stdout

I am trying to retrieve data from an API and immediate write the JSON response directly to a file and not store any part of the response in memory. The reason for this requirement is because I'm executing this script on a AWS Linux EC2 that only has 2GB of memory, and if I try to hold everything in memory and then write the responses to a file, the process will fail due to not enough memory.

I've tried using `f.write()` as well as `sys.stdout.write()`, but both of these approaches seemed to only write the file after all the queries were executed.  While this worked with my small example, it didn't work when dealing with my actual data.

The problem with both approaches below is that the file doesn't populate until the loop is complete. This will not work with my actual process, as the machine doesn't have enough memory to hold the all the responses in memory.

**How can I adapt either of the approaches below, or come up with something new, to write data received from the API immediately to a file without saving anything in memory?**

Note: I'm using Python 3.7 but happy to update if there is something that would make this easier.

## My Approach 1

```py
# script1.py
import requests
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/uuid")
        data = r.json()
        f.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")
f.close()
```

## My Approach 2

```py
# script2.py
import request
import json
import sys

for i in range(0, 100):
    r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/uuid")
    data = r.json()
    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(data))
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

With approach 2, I tried using the `>` to redirect the output to a file:

```sh
script2.py > data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.iter_content` to download the content in chunks. For example:

```
import requests


url = 'https://httpbin.org/uuid'

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open('data.json', 'wb') as f_out:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
            f_out.write(chunk)
```

Saves `data.json` with content:

```
{
  "uuid": "991a5843-35ca-47b3-81d3-258a6d4ce582"
}
```